# Adding months to DateTime with DateInterval changes original date to match new date

Tags: php, datetime

I have this pretty simple code:

```
$start_date = new DateTime($post['start_date']);
$end_date = $start_date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $start_date->getTimestamp(); // 1351836000
echo $end_date->getTimestamp(); // 1351836000
```

Of course, both end up as the same timestamp because adding the date interval affects the original $start_date. So how do I go about this so I can keep the original $start_date yet add 6 months to it in another variable?

I tried this with no luck:

```
$start_date = new DateTime($post['start_date']);
$start_date_actual = $start_date;
$end_date = $start_date_actual->add(new DateInterval('P6M'))->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Variables hold references to objects, not the objects themselves.  So assignment just gets you more variables pointing to the same object, not multiple copies of the object.

If you *want* a copy, use the [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword:

```
$end_date = clone $start_date;
$end_date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take your pick:

```
$start_date = new DateTime($post['start_date']);
$end_date = new DateTime($post['start_date']);
$end_date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
```

or

```
$start_date = new DateTime($post['start_date']);
$end_date = clone $start_date;
$end_date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Clone the start date before you modify it:

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = clone $start_date;
$end_date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $start_date->getTimestamp();
echo $end_date->getTimestamp();
```

See the manual for more information

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php